# Footer Overlapping Content When Resizing

Tags: html, css, footer

I created a sticky footer, and it appears to be staying at the bottom of the page. The only problem is that when I minimize my browser by dragging the bottom of the browser up, the content above overlaps with the footer. The Content div contains images which are on top of the footer when I minimize. Also the type within the footer appears above the images (when minimized). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

<----- HTML Structure ---->

```
<div class="supercontainer"

    <div class="nav"></div>

    <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="push"></div>

    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer"></div>
```

<----- Relevant CSS ----->

```
.supercontainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
  position: relative;
  }

.footer {
   background-color: black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
 }
  .push {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I [couldn't reproduce](http://jsbin.com/jaguf/1/edit) the issue, please consider providing an online demo to demonstrate the issue in action.

Answer (score 0):

To get the content to push down the footer, you need to give the content div a negative bottom margin that matches the footer's height.

```
.supercontainer {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -100px;
   position: relative;
  }

.footer {
   background-color: black;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
 }
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for your response. Maybe I wasn't clear in my post. I'm trying to get my footer to work the same as it does as in Hashem's  example. I think I may have figured out what the problem was....I had the content div set to 100vh, which was causing overlap for some reason?